# how php orm doctrine fetch object and its related joins

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm

I am using **[doctrine ORM](http://doctrine-project.org)** in my php project.
I wonder how doctrine fetch an object(its table) from database?

- Does it fetch all related **joins** of that object and so all related objects?
  say **$author** has an association with **$article**. Does `$author = $authorRepository->find($id)` fetch the article table ?
- Does it fetch the **joins of joins** of that object?

I faced this question when I did a dump of an ORM object. I saw all of its associations titles. for example: doctrine dump of $author:

```
object(stdClass)#1212 (4) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(6) "author"
  ["ID"]=>
    int(12)
  ["num"]=>
    int(6059996)
  ["CreateTimestamp"]=>
    int(1316602238)
  ["articles"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
        string(7) "article"
      [1]=>
        string(7) "article"
      [2]=>
        string(7) "article"
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific and provide some code for context. I also wonder a lot of things, like if you've tried to do any of this.

Comment: The associations as strings are actually from the virtual proxy object, which is a copy of the real entity with some storage logic in order to accomplish the lazy loading when you request for one of those articles. You can try dumping after and before calling `$author->getArticles()` to see the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder how doctrine fetch an object(its table) from database?

Basically using the [**Data Mapper Pattern**](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

> Does it fetch all related joins of that object and so all related
>   objects?  Does it fetch the joins of joins of that object?

**No, it doesn't.** Unless you specify it using [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), the [query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) or [native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

If you get one object within its repository, say: `$author = $authorRepository->find($id)`; It will fetch from only one table (with exception of [class table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance))

If you then ask the `$author` object to retrieve its relationships, say: `$author->getBooks();` without previously specifying it (joining with DQL/SQL) then it will use [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), achieved by the **virtual proxy pattern** and will perform another **separated query to retrieve the data**.